# How use variable in factory boy build

Tags: python, factory-boy

I have the Factory like this

```
import factory

from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Note:

    write: bool
    read: bool

class NoteFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Note

    write= False
    read= False

note = NoteFactory.build(write=True)
print(note.write)

output: True
```

It is worked ok

I want to use variable in this case:

```
var_write = 'write'
note = NoteFactory.build(var_write =True)
print(note.var_write)

ouput : Note.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'var_write'
```

It can not work
How can use variable in this case or is there some workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to specify the `field` you're setting to `True` in a variable; i.e:

```
>>> var_field = "write"
>>> NoteFactory.build(...)  # The "..." is the syntax we're interested in
Note(read=False, write=True)
>>> var_field = "read"
>>> NoteFactory.build(...)  # The "..." is the syntax we're interested in
Note(read=True, write=False)
```

In that case, you need to use Python's [`**kwargs` argument passing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).
A very detailed example would be:

```py
>>> var_field = "write"
>>> kwargs = {var_field: True}
>>> kwargs
{"write": True}
>>> NoteFactory.build(**kwargs)
Note(read=False, write=True)
```

It's simpler to write it in a single line though:

```py
>>> var_field = "write"
>>> NoteFactory(**{var_field: True})
Note(read=False, write=True)
```

However, note that this pattern will make it harder to analyse a large codebase later on: it's much harder to see *where* you're setting `write=True`, as the definition is now spread across several lines.

As a side note, you can also write `NoteFactory(...)` instead of `NoteFactory.build(...)`: both will have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you very much, It has worked. That is what I am looking for